# Maven - Access properties on parent pom from a child pom

Tags: maven, build, release, release-management

In a multi module project structure as

```
myApp
|-moduleA
|---pom.xml
|-moduleB
|---pom.xml
|-pom.xml
```

If i have the following properties in the parent.pom

```
  <properties>
   <moduleA.version>4.67</moduleA.version>
   <moduleB.version>4.68</moduleB.version>
  </properties>
```

How can i access the properties in the parent pom from any of the child poms? I tried this on the child pom but it didnt work.

```
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
  <version>${moduleA.version}</version>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a real multi-module build you should never define the modules to have different versions. They should have the same version which make releasing possible and other things as well. Otherwise you should not use the multi-module setup than use simple single modules which are separated.

Comment: In a real multi module project (i.e. one where the versions are not specified in the child modules), which versions of the child modules are used from the local repository? Does it always use the latest versions?

Comment: The version is inherited by the parent module. Take a deep look into this: http://sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Thanks this is what i was doing initially but i changed it as a result of suggestions given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670158/maven-with-jenkins-update-parent-pom-version-of-dependency . Looks like i might have to revert back to making each module independent. Thanks

Comment: The problem with the project you mentioned is that i would never put jsP's into different modules cause they belong to the war module. Sometimes it can be useful to make separate modules for the java part but not for the jsp parts or you have multiple war's.

Comment: The problem with multiple war files is that there will need to be lots of changes for cross context communication and session handling which is not really worth the effort. I agree that they should all be in one war file but i dont have any other option as that is the only way i can split it.

Comment: "If you have a real multi-module build you should never define the modules to have different versions." I disagree, an obvious example would be a multimodule pom encapsulating client and server you don't want to have to release a new server version just to fix a bug on the client!

Comment: But if you have multi-module build you have to otherwise you shouldnt have multi-module build

Answer (score 2):

This should work. One possible reason I can think of is that perhaps you don't actually *inherit* the pom where these properties are defined (i.e. it's not defined as your `<parent>` directly or indirectly), but you only have a main pom that *aggregates* your projects. It's a guess, though.

Comment: Yes you are right. I dont have the '<parent>' information on the child modules. In maven 3 i dont have to define these. The parent pom just includes the '<modules>' section which specified which modules are part of the project. Will it only work if i have the '<parent>' tag on the child modules?

Comment: If you use only the modules part in your root pom this is an aggregation project not a real multi-module build, cause it misses the inheritance from it's parent pom.

Comment: That worked for me after adding `<parent>` information.