# What does <version>${jersey-version}</version> mean in pom.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jax-rs, pom.xml

I downloaded sample atmosphere jax-rs source code here - http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.atmosphere.samples%22%20AND%20a%3A%22atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat%22

I downloaded the war and the sources.jar. And the pom.xml is viewable in a browser - http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/atmosphere/samples/atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat/1.0.7/atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat-1.0.7.pom

I want to copy some of the dependencies from this pom.xml into my own pom.xml but I see things like -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I presume `${logback-version}` and `${jersey-version}` are placeholders but where are they actually set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the parent pom. In the top of the pom, there is a reference to parent pom, which holds the values.

Some more rationale in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708230/maven-access-properties-on-parent-pom-from-a-child-pom) - basically, it keeps the versions in sync in a multi-module project.

Parent definition looks something like this:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <relativePath>../my-parent</relativePath>
</parent>
```

like explained in the [inheritance section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) of the pom doc pages.